# Global Mutex can cause DoS of it's own application

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

The application which can be run by different users (Admin, Non-Admin) on Windows at once. It has a critical section which cannot be executed at the same time by different (or the same) user.

To prevent that I'm using Global Mutex from WinApi by calling:
`CreateMutex(NULL, true, "Global\\MyMutex");` and then after job is done Mutex is released. "Global" prefix is added to make Mutex visible between all Windows sessions. (It's optional but I want to present that this Mutex is not Local one).

And now the problem:

Assume there is an attacker which want to prevent critical section to be executed by anyone, so she create a program which create a mutex with name `"Global\\MyMutex"` and never release it... In that way she was able to perform DoS attack on my application for other users - as they are not able to reach critical section.

The question is - How can I prevent such attack scenario with Global Mutex?

Comment: If the attacker has gained read/write access to your running machine then that's not really a DOS that's a takeover and DOS is the least of your worries. Why wouldn't she just wipe the HDD?

Comment: Sorry but your question is absurd: If the attacker can obviously execute arbitrary code, there are much more important problems than creating Global mutexes. Like a fork bomb or wiping data.

Comment: @Galik This is not true for non-admin users.

Comment: @Superlokkus This is not true for non-admin users.

Comment: I assume your application is running as its own user or as admin? Other users should not have write access to its files and directories. If they gain that access then they can do a lot more damage than simply creating the lock file. They could delete everything the application controls.

Comment: [Raymond Chen has written about a similar problem here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060620-13/?p=30813)

Answer (score 0):

First, doing it with a global mutex requires admin. Second, you can do it with a plain named mutex, in which yes, a malicious app can prevent your app from running. But a malicious app running in your system may do far more problematic things than just blocking your application.

Solutions:

1. Create a named mutex based on some weird unique string (say a CLSID) so a malicious app won't detect it easily.
2. Do not lock per-application. You may issue a warning on a mutex found locked for a long time, but still let the user proceed. It depends on what your application is designed to do. In my opinion this is the better approach.
3. Do not bother. If one malicious-app creator *does* bother in attacking *your* application, you would have been long successful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Not use a global mutex.

That's basically it.

But you say, "How can I stop my application doing something twice at the same time?"

Well, what would happen if *the attacker* did that thing over and over? It would screw up your application because nobody else would be able to do it at the same time, right? Mutex or no mutex.

So you need to figure out how to make it so it can be done at the same time.

Your other option is to declare that you don't really care about security. Sometimes that's an option, like if you trust everyone who logs into the computer. It doesn't look good if someone does decide to attack your application.